# Mi trigger compila pero no funciona

Tags: oracle, trigger

tengo un problema con el trigger para reducir stock. El trigger me compila y todo pero cuanto inserto datos a mi tabla detalle_venta, en la tabla producto no me reduce la cantidad.

Estas son mis tablas:

```
create table producto
(
    proId int primary key not null,
    prodNombre varchar(40),
    prodCant int,
    prodPrecio decimal(7,2)
 );
commit;

create table detalle_venta
(
    dvId int primary key not null,
    proId int,
    foreign key(proId) references producto(proId),
    venId int,
    foreign key(venId) references venta(venId),
    dvCantidad int,
    dvPrecioart decimal(7,2),
    dvTotal decimal(7,2)
);
commit;

create trigger ACTUALIZAR_STOCK_TRG
after insert or delete or update
on DETALLE_VENTA
for each row 
begin
if(inserting or updating)
then
UPDATE PRODUCTO
set PRODCANT = PRODCANT - :new.dvcantidad
where PROID = :new.DVID;
end if;
if(inserting or deleting)
then 
update PRODUCTO
set PRODCANT = PRODCANT + :new.dvcantidad
where PROID = :old.DVID;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: No es por qué al insertar disminuyes y sumas new.dvcantidad? Por lo que pareciera que no funciona pero si te fijas haces esa operación siempre, al actualizar debería solo restar y al borrar sumar pero al insertar "no hace nada"